# Making instances reach towards each other

Tags: geometry-nodes, meta-objects

I would like to make instances reach each other depending on the distance (like metaballs would) and, if close enough, merge into one without a border between them. Can somebody please suggest a node setup for that? I can do boolean but I need exactly that reaching in proximity effect

1. render of what I have
2. the current GN setup
3. the result I want to achieve with GN

[image: the current render]

[image: the current setup]

[image: the result I want to achieve with GN]

Comment: I would try mesh to volume and then volume to mesh. That's pretty much how metaballs work, they use remeshing...

Comment: If you look at the nodes setup I tried to do exactly that. However, it does not make instances try to reach each other while in proximity like meatballs do